# Windows search for specific filenames only inside in specific foldernames

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-search, filenames

I want to search in windows all files with names "text" only inside folders with "1H" in name.

So is it possible to search something like that:

```
searching_filename='text' searching_folders='*1H*'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to open a Windows Explorer window and type this query in the search field :

`filename:text folder:*1H*`